# How to make a post request without form and without getting error 400

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending a post request without a form in asp.net. I'm getting error 400.

**AJAX**

```
function deteleCategorieBtn(id) {
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?")) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'categories/delete/' + id,
        success: function () {
            var dataTable = $('#kt_datatable').DataTable();
            dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);    
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log(request, error);
        }
    })
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
// POST: Categories/Delete/5
        [Route("delete/{id?}")]
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            var category = await _context.Categories
                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if(category != null){
                _context.Categories.Remove(category);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { error = true, messages = "Categorie doesn't exist" }, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
            }

            return Json(new { success = true, messages = "Registered well" }, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
        }
    }
```

- On the console, the url is correct
- I tried changing the type from POST to DELETE in ajax part, and HttpPost to HttpDelete - Didn't work
- I used the very same controller code successfully with a form that looks like that :

```
<form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ? ?');">
      <button type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon"></button>
</form>
```

EDIT :
Found this error message :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure how the attributes of the controller class look like, but it seems to me that this might be problem:
// POST: Categories/Delete/5
        [Route("delete/{id?}")] - you are missing the "categories" part of path

Comment: I've got ```[Route("categories")]
    public class CategoriesController : Controller```` at the top, the routing works well

Comment: Yea, I think this might be the problem. One option is to make AJAX call of type DELETE to url categories/id but I'm not sure about that and you probably don't want that. What I think correct solution to this is not using ROUTE attribute at class level, rather use RoutePrefix attribute - [RoutePrefix("categories")] ... class : Controller { ... [Route("Delete/{id?}"] ... method ...

Comment: P.s.: Check the correct address of the working form POST in your developer tools...

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem as explained in my post, I'm able with a form to delete correctly with the controller's code. Already tried ajax making a DELETE call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an Antiforgery token while doing the ajax post.

Add an antiforgerytoken like below in your page

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

This will be added in a hidden input field

While doing the ajax post, send the token like below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'categories/delete/' + id,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('XSRF-TOKEN',
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
    success: function () {
        var dataTable = $('#kt_datatable').DataTable();
        dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);    
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        console.log(request, error);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Still got the error message and found out that the AntiForgeryToken is hardcoded to be used with a form. Added informations to the question

Comment: @Joel, Is the 400 solved now?. And which provider are you using for your database?

Comment: Oh yes ! It's solved but I'm now having an error 500. Thank you

Comment: Which namespace are you using to have the FirstOrDefault extension method?.

Comment: I managed to resolved the error. I forgot what it was but it was something silly I had forgotten. It's your solution that opened my eyes and resolved the main issue